# why does my dynamically allocated array implementation of queue data structure NOT update on the second call?

Tags: c++, data-structures, queue, new-operator, circular-queue

I'm learning Data Structures as required of me by my university. I've implemented the Queue DS using Dynamic Array but it somehow doesn't work. It updates the value on the first enqueue method call but from the second call onward, it does nothing.

**MY CODE**

```
#include <iostream>
#define MAXSIZE 8

class Queue
{
private:
    int *arr;
    int front;
    int rear;
    int itemsCount;

public:
    Queue()
    {      
        arr = new int[MAXSIZE];
        front = -1;
        rear = -1;
        itemsCount = 0;
    }

    ~Queue()
    {
        delete[] arr;
    }

    int dequeue()
    {

        int x = arr[front];
        front = (front + 1) % MAXSIZE;
        itemsCount--;
        return x;
    }

    void enqueue(int x)
    {
        if (empty())
        {
            front++;
        }

        rear = (rear + 1) % MAXSIZE;
        arr[rear] = x;
        itemsCount++;
    }

    bool full() const
    {
        if (itemsCount == MAXSIZE)
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    bool empty() const
    {
        if (itemsCount == 0)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    Queue myQ;

    myQ.enqueue(11);
    myQ.enqueue(22); // This doesn't update the array at 1th index
    myQ.enqueue(33);
    myQ.enqueue(44);
    myQ.enqueue(55);
    myQ.enqueue(66);
    myQ.enqueue(77);
    myQ.enqueue(88);

    std::cout << myQ.dequeue() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

P.S I know the implementation is incomplete and I haven't handled all the edge cases yet. That's because I couldn't get the normal case to work.

P.P.S It works with Static Array. But not with Dynamically allocated one.

Comment: `if (condition) return true; else return false;` is better written as `return condition;`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Thank you for replying. I'll take that into consideration. But it doesn't solve the issue I'm facing.

Comment: … hence I wrote a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the array was being updated and the program was running as it should have when I performed the dequeue operations and displayed the values on screen. But the debugger somehow was only showing the value at the first index of the dynamically allocated array.

[array pointer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XXFq.png)